# Difference between lua-sqlite3 and lsqlite3

Tags: sqlite, lua, openwrt

I would like to do a database in sqlite in OpenWRT using Lua, and I would like to know if there is any conceptual difference between libraries lua-sqlite3 and lsqlite3 ?

Looking at their documentation they seem to be different libraries for the same thing.

http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki

http://www.mroth.net/lua-sqlite3/index.html

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems no conceptual difference.

Seems also that the lua-sqlite3 is no longer working under lua2. Am not sure.

The problem is that the syntax is different. So you have to rewrite old scripts if you use lsqite3 ...

Just like you would appreciate to have more info on the differences between lua-sqlite3 and lsqlite3